# iphone app is logging out frequently

Tags: ios, logout

I've developed an app where in the entered username and password by user is saved using `NSUserDefaults`.

Any request from user for any service needs this username to be sent. So using `NSUserDefaults` I'm sending username for each request. Still the iPhone app is logging out without clicking the logout button and starts from the beginning asking for username and password.

As facebook app and others remains once logged in. Please let me know why the app is logging out frequently without clicking logout button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of server are you connecting to? What protocol? It is likely that `NSUserDefaults` has nothing to do with the problem you are facing.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Yes the problem is not from NSUserDefaults,i just mentioned that i'm keeping username throughout the app using NSUserDefaults.But why app is getting logged out i'm not able to understand.When it goes to background it should start from the same place where it was closed,but for me app is logged out and again starts from the beginning.

Comment: it gets killed maybe ;)

Comment: The reason for the logout could be for several reasons such as a simple time-out  because it has been to long since the last activity to the server setting up a [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) and loosing contact with your app.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this.How should i go further to fix this problem.Thanks

Comment: @user3162102 Let me take a wild guess to the effect that your client may not handle cookies as the service expects. But really, you need to post more specific information about your issue if you want more than guesses.

Comment: I've created a app that has a tableview that lists all emaiids where in these mailids i'm taking from server with that url added with userid.But when client exits from this app and again if he opens this app from background its not showing the list of mail ids(from where it was exited)but takes user from the first page that is login page and asks for userid and password.

Comment: @user3162102 Now sounds like you are terminating an (HTTP) session when exiting the app (which would be normal behavior). You perhaps have to store the table view's current scrolling position on the client (e.g. in `NSUserDefaults` :) and recover it "manually" when the app restarts.

Comment: @Drux Recover it manually means i should send a request whenever app restarts??Is my understanding correct?But I'm making request for email ids in viewdidload method only,but still app is getting logged out

Answer (score 1):

On launch check if there is a saved username and password, if so use them. When the user enters these save them.

You need to look at the page source from the server for the form request of the credentials, create the form response with the credentials and post it. This is doable and actually not very hard. On one project I did this for auto login and respond to many form requests so the user never saw them.

Do not use NSUserDefaults for credentials, it is not secure. Instead use the Keychain, it is secure.

Comment: Thanks for your response.The problem i'm facing is app developed is logging out frequently.When app is at background it should start from the same page where it was closed but for this app it starts from the beginning of the page asking for user credentials

Comment: :"You need to look at the page source from the server for the form request of the credentials, create the form response with the credentials and post it".Please explain

Comment: You are going to have to learn how html forms work and how to create form responses in code and send them. There are lot's of sources in the Internet.